# Trying to map on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, fetch

I added the Nutrition file

```js
const Nutrition = () => {




  return(
      <div>
        <p>Label</p>
        <p>Quantity</p>
        <p>Unit</p>
      </div>
  )



}
    



export default Nutrition
```

I'm trying to map something in React but I'm getting this error map is not function. I'm trying to fetch an Api and now I'm trying to map another component to it, but the error is still there. Could someone help me or give me a hint

```js
const ApiNutrition = () => {




const [nutritions, setNutritions] = useState([])

useEffect( () => {
  
    
   getNutritions();
}, [])

const getNutritions = async () => {

    const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-data?app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}&ingr=1%20large%20apple`)
    
    const data = await response.json();
    setNutritions(data.totalNutrientsKCal)
    console.log(data.totalNutrientsKCal);
 
}


    return(

        <div>

            <form className="container text-center">
                <input classname="form-control" type="text" placeholder="CALORIES"/>
                <button classname="form-control" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

           {nutritions.map(nutrition => (
              <Nutrition />

           ))}
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default ApiNutrition
```

Comment: Is `data.totalNutrientsKCal` an array? I'm thinking it's possible that it's not actually an array, in which case you wouldn't be able to `map` over it.

Comment: no it's an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I can see you have two places where you are setting the value of `nutritions`. One is while defining with useState(), and the other is after API call with `setNutritions`.

The error you are getting is `map is not a function`, it means somehow type of `nutritions` is not an array.

while defining with `useState` you are providing `[]` as default value so it means the error is with the API, the response you are getting from `API` which you are passing to `setNutritions` is not an array.

You can debug the API response type by `typeof data.totalNutrientsKCal` inside `console.log`

Comment: but I though we could still through an object?

Comment: Ok I understand now, thank you so much for your help

Comment: for Object you can do `Object.keys(nutritions).map(key => (<Nutrition />))`